# wso2 SAML issuer field length

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to register the Wordpress SAML 2.0 plugin against WSO2 IS.

The two communicate, but on debugging I found the following error:

> TID: [0] [IS] [2015-08-26 04:13:36,603]  WARN
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor}
>   -  A Service Provider with the Issuer 'http://xxxx.example.com/wp-content/plugins/saml-20-single-sign-on/saml/www/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/1'
>   is not registered. Service Provider should be registered in advance.
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor}

When I checked the configuration of the service provider, I discovered that the WSO2 UI had truncated the Issuer to this:

```
http://xxxx.example.com/wp-content/plugins/saml-20-single-sign-on/saml/www/module.php/saml/sp/me
```

Is there any way to extend the permitted length of the 'issuer' field, or to bypass the UI and edit this value directly?

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround to overcome this truncation of issuer name. Instead of registering the SP using the UI. You can register the SP using a file based method as explained in [1].

I tested the by creating an SP with the issuer value('http://xxxx.example.com/wp-content/plugins/saml-20-single-sign-on/saml/www/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/1) given in this question on IS 5.1.0 pack. It works fine.

In order to get SAML working for the given issuer name

1. Use the below template to create the service provider configuration,
   (Change the values as required)

---

```
<ServiceProvider>
        <Issuer>http://xxxx.example.com/wp-content/plugins/saml-20-single-sign-on/saml/www/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/1</Issuer>
        <AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
          <AssertionConsumerServiceURL>http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/home.jsp</AssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        </AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
        <DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/home.jsp</DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        <EnableSingleLogout>true</EnableSingleLogout>
        <SLOResponseURL></SLOResponseURL>
        <SLORequestURL></SLORequestURL>
        <SAMLDefaultSigningAlgorithmURI>http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1</SAMLDefaultSigningAlgorithmURI>
        <SAMLDefaultDigestAlgorithmURI>http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1</SAMLDefaultDigestAlgorithmURI>
        <SignResponse>false</SignResponse>
        <ValidateSignatures>false</ValidateSignatures>
        <EncryptAssertion>false</EncryptAssertion>
        <CertAlias></CertAlias>
        <EnableAttributeProfile>true</EnableAttributeProfile>
        <IncludeAttributeByDefault>true</IncludeAttributeByDefault>
        <ConsumingServiceIndex>2104589</ConsumingServiceIndex>
        <EnableAudienceRestriction>false</EnableAudienceRestriction>
        <AudiencesList>
          <Audience></Audience>
        </AudiencesList>
        <EnableRecipients>false</EnableRecipients>
        <RecipientList>
          <Recipient></Recipient>
        </RecipientList>
        <EnableIdPInitiatedSSO>false</EnableIdPInitiatedSSO>
        <EnableIdPInitSLO>false</EnableIdPInitSLO>
        <ReturnToURLList>
          <ReturnToURL></ReturnToURL>
        </ReturnToURLList>
    </ServiceProvider>
```

---

2. Add the service provider configuration to /repository/conf/identity/sso-idp-config.xml under  section.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+a+SP+and+IdP+Using+Configuration+Files